# How can I refactor this horrid abstract java class with multiple generics into something "better"?

Tags: java, abstract-class

We have multiple search pages in our JSF web application which have similar functionality:

- They have search results (Call these objects T)
- The have an object which contains the search criteria (Call this object C)
- They have the ability to save the search criteria with a name (Call this object S)

So these all use a JSF page backing bean which all extend an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractSearch<T, C, S> implements Serializable {
```

For example:

```
public class FooSearch extends AbstractSearch<Foo, FooCriteria, FooSavedCriteria> 
    implements Serializable {
```

One of the issues I see is that the classes that are put into T, C, and S do not share an superType with another T, C, or S class.  They do have similar methods though.  For example, all of the S-type classes have a "getName()" method.  I can't use a common superclass to get this name.  Instead, I have to put the following method in the AbstractSearch class and wrap all of my objects with it:

```
abstract String getNameFromSavedCriteria(S);
```

And then implement the conversion method in each of the subclass:

```
@Override
String getNameFromSavedCriteria(FooSavedCriteria criteria) {
    return criteria.getName();
}
```

Is this a bad practice?  The page is littered with these conversion-helper methods.

Another example of what, appears to be, strange coding.  Here is a stereotypical public method of AbstractSearch:

```
public void runSearch() {

    if (simpleSearch == true) {
        clearAdvancedSearchFields(); // abstract method
    }        

    populateSearchFromForm(); // abstract method

    try {
        setResults(processRunSearch()); // abstract method
        cacheResults(results); // abstract method
        cacheSearch(search); // abstract method

        if (getResults().isEmpty()) {
            Messages.addGlobalWarn("No results found");
        }

        if (formAutoHide) {
            searchFormVisible = getResults().isEmpty();
        }

    } catch (MyException ex) {
        FacesUtils.addGlobalError(ex);
    }
}
```

Again, is this a bad practice?  Is there a better way of handling an abstract class like this which has a lot of common functionality but not a lot of common classes on which to operate?

I should also note that perhaps, @ some point, I would be able to refactor T/C/S into all using common subtypes so that these conversion-helper methods could go away.  Still...I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? As far as I understand, `T`, `C` and `S` are three classes with different functionalities, therefore I would not necessarily expect them to have a common super-class or interface. Your Getter (`getName(S)`) is somewhat counter-intuitive. A Getter should not have any paramters.

Comment: I edited the page to be more clear.  I didn't mean T/C/S are classes that share a superclass.  I meant that each class that implements AbstractSearch and provides the definitions of these generics uses objects that are similar to other classes that also use them...but those classes have no official relationship.  (See above for the example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong with the "stereotypical public method of AbstractSearch". Abstract classes define abstract methods so they can use them already.

To solve your problem, I think a big step into the right direction is to define bounds for T, C, S so they can use each other on an abstract level.

E.g:

```
abstract class Criteria {
    abstract String getName();
    String getNameFromSavedCriteria(SavedCriteria s) {
        return s.getName();
    }
}
interface SavedCriteria {
    String getName();
}
public abstract class AbstractSearch<T, C extends Criteria, S extends SavedCriteria> implements Serializable {

   void foo() {
       System.out.println("Hello. Searching for " + getCriteria().getName());
   }
}
```

T, C, S don't necessarily need a common class, C & S maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Android's [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you see it has 3 class parameters.

I say as long as those classes don't overlap in functionality, then there's no reason to refactor it.

Comment: Ah, great, thanks for the example.  Using 3 generic classes just seemed "icky" but, right there in your example is a class that looks similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example `runSearch()` follows the template method pattern and I don't really see much of a problem with it.

I also don't really see a problem with 3 generics in your class.  Take a look at the new Java 8 Stream/Collect/Reduce methods which often have 3 types.

In my code when I have as many generics like that, sometimes I make a marker interface but that only makes since if you have several different implementations of a `FooSearch` that all use the same or generics.